# Why nodejs package on github has diffrence with the same package downloaded by npm commit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I download nodejs package by commit: npm install -g package_name
But I find some package downloaded has diffrent files with ther same package on Github.Why?

Comment: when we run `npm install -g package_name` there is version associated with the same:

please specify the version when installing similar to the one you see on github..then you will find that the two will match

`npm install -g package_name@<SPECIFIC VERSION>`

Comment: please refer this :https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A developer creates a package when he thinks the code is stable, and continues developing on future updates.

So github code is Work in Progress code for the next update, npm package is the latest stable version of the package.

In above case, if you want to see the npm package code in github look for the tag with the package version.

Also files in npm package can be compiled code while github contains the source code. Using `.gitignore` a developer can exclude compiled files from github repo and using `.npmignore` a developer can exclude source files from npm package (not often the case, but can be done)

So the reason for difference in code can be one of these.

Comment: I just figure out that the difference appears because some file are included in the .gitignore.  Thanks.